# Save any new/changed entity respectively in Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

first, I was only trying to update a modified model. Lets say, we talk about "Article" as a model.
The following method is implemented in a class called "Articles":

```
    public static void SaveArticle(Article article) 
    {
        if (article.Id == 0)
        {
            webEntities.Articles.Add(article);
        }
        else
        {
            webEntities.Articles.Attach(article);
            webEntities.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        webEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

So whenever I want to save an modified article in a controller action, I just have to call "Articles.SaveArticle(myArticle);", which works as expected. 
So far so good but this means I would need to implement this redundantly for every model/entity.

Then I thought about something like a template-pattern. I.e. a class called "Entity" where "Article" inherits from "Entity". 
Furthermore, a class called "Entities" contains a static method like this:

```
    public static void SaveEntity(Entity entity) 
    {
        if (Entity.Id == 0) // <-- Problem 1
        {
            webEntities.Entities.Add(entity); // <-- Problem 2
        }
        else
        {
            webEntities.Entities.Attach(entity); // <-- Problem 3
            webEntities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; // <-- Problem 4
        }

        webEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

So I would not need to implement it redundantly but I don't know how to solve the problems mentioned in the code above.
Do I think too complicated or what would be a best practice to my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: Are you using entity framework 4 or 5?

Comment: It says Version 4.4.0.0 and Runtime Version v4.0.30319

Comment: Do you use `DbContext` or `ObjectCOntext`?

Comment: The object "webEntities" is an instance of "WebEntities" which inherits from "DbContext"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics.

```
public static void Save<T>(T entity)
    where T : class
{
    webEntities.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(entity);
    webEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

[`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is an extension method in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)
First I wondered why AddOrUpdate was not known but it worked then after adding "System.Data.Entity.Migrations" manually (it was not suggested by the compiler)